# upload image to server modifying name

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6

I am building a form with laravel 5.6 and where I save a name and a user photo,
but i need the photo to be stored with the username.
I show the code of my store

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

            $entrada=$request->all();
            if($archivo=$request->file('foto_dni')){
                $nombre=$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
                $archivo->move('fotosdni', $nombre);
                $entrada['foto_dni']=$nombre;
            }

            Persona::create($entrada);
    }
```

**I can get the username with**
$request->nombre;

but I don't know how to assign that name to the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `->storeAs()` method available on the Laravel's request object.

You can use it like:

```
$path = $request->file('foto_dni')->storeAs(
    'YOUR_FILE_PATH', 'YOUR_FILE_NAME'
);
```